# Iterate over all values of a bash completion

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete

Consider:

```
$ ssh fo<tab>
foo  fool  football
```

How would I write a for loop to iterate over those values?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for SERVER in $(ssh fo<MAGIC HERE>) ; do echo $SERVER ; done
```

The list could change regularly, so hardcoding the values is not an option. In the specific case of SSH, I understand that I could grep the SSH config file for the matching hosts. But some other completion situations arise, such as:

```
$ git che<tab>
checkout      cherry        cherry-pick
```

The answer should be useful for these other ad-hoc completions as well.

Comment: @Theophrastus Thank you, I'll see where I can run with it. This quote is terrific: `It has been extensively documented that programmers are willing to put in long hours of effort in order to save ten minutes of "unnecessary" labor. This is known as optimization.`

Comment: What's the use case for iterating over the `git` sub-commands?

Comment: Maybe this post of 2015 is useful: https://brbsix.github.io/2015/11/29/accessing-tab-completion-programmatically-in-bash/

Comment: I think that a couple of additions are required for your description, for example `ls -` would return only `ls --` and needs processing again to get all compination after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**compgen** will work only with one word, like the following :

```
compgen -c git
```

Here is a custom solution for your case :

You will have first to source bash-completion script, then set the **COMP_*** vars so they meet this use case and then trigger programmatically the completion with the native `bash_completion` function **xfunc** and the results will then be gathered in `COMPREPLY` array (example taken from [here](https://brbsix.github.io/2015/11/29/accessing-tab-completion-programmatically-in-bash/)):

```
# load bash-completion helper functions
source /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion

# array of words in command line
COMP_WORDS=(git c)

# index of the word containing cursor position
COMP_CWORD=1

# command line
COMP_LINE='git c'

# index of cursor position
COMP_POINT=${#COMP_LINE}

# execute completion function
_xfunc git _git

# print completions to stdout
printf '%s\n' "${COMPREPLY[@]}"
```

P.S : To know the exact functions called during a command completion :
use `complete -p <command>`

Output :

```
checkout
cherry
cherry-pick
clean
clone
column
commit
config
credential
```

For a full overview of this, you can visit the owner post [here](https://brbsix.github.io/2015/11/29/accessing-tab-completion-programmatically-in-bash/)

Comment: This is terrific! I feel like Harry Potter discovering a new spell!

Comment: hihi please don't forget to mark it as resolved if it's the case :)

Comment: I'm going to give the question a day or two to develop additional answers before marking, which is SOP here. Thank you!